# Ruby On Rails and "external classes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rss

I have RSS-reader class for Ruby, and I'd want to use it in rails, where does the rss_reader.rb go? To "libs/rss_reader.rb"?

I tried that, then requiring it in controller, but I get error: *'MissingSourceFile (no such file to load -- lib/RssReader)'*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you put your class in "RAILS_ROOT/lib/" it will be autoloaded and require 'lib/rss_reader' should work.