# How to copy file across buckets using aws-s3 or aws-sdk gem in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

The aws-s3 documentation says:

```
  # Copying an object
  S3Object.copy 'headshot.jpg', 'headshot2.jpg', 'photos'
```

But how do I copy `heashot.jpg` from the `photos` bucket to the `archive` bucket for example

Thanks!

Deb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `right_aws` gem:

```
# With s3 being an S3 object acquired via S3Interface.new
# Copies key1 from bucket b1 to key1_copy in bucket b2:
s3.copy('b1', 'key1', 'b2', 'key1_copy')
```

the gotcha I ran into is that if you have `pics/1234/yourfile.jpg` the `bucket` is only `pics` and the `key` is `1234/yourfile.jpg`

I got the answer from here: [How do I copy files between buckets using s3 from a rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769848/how-do-i-copy-files-between-buckets-using-s3-from-a-rails-application)

Answer (score 28):

**AWS-SDK gem.** [S3Object#copy_to](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#copy_to-instance_method)

```
Copies data from the current object to another object in S3.
S3 handles the copy so the client does not need to fetch the 
data and upload it again. You can also change the storage 
class and metadata of the object when copying.
```

It uses **copy_object** method [internal](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ruby/blob/master/lib/aws/s3/s3_object.rb#L592), so the copy functionality allows you to copy objects within or between your S3 buckets, and optionally to replace the metadata associated with the object in the process.

**Standard method (download/upload)**

[image]

**Copy method**

[image]

**Code sample:**

```
require 'aws-sdk'

AWS.config(
  :access_key_id     => '***',
  :secret_access_key => '***',
  :max_retries       => 10
)

file     = 'test_file.rb'
bucket_0 = {:name => 'bucket_from', :endpoint => 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'}
bucket_1 = {:name => 'bucket_to',   :endpoint => 's3.amazonaws.com'}

s3_interface_from = AWS::S3.new(:s3_endpoint => bucket_0[:endpoint])
bucket_from       = s3_interface_from.buckets[bucket_0[:name]]
bucket_from.objects[file].write(open(file))

s3_interface_to   = AWS::S3.new(:s3_endpoint => bucket_1[:endpoint])
bucket_to         = s3_interface_to.buckets[bucket_1[:name]]
bucket_to.objects[file].copy_from(file, {:bucket => bucket_from})
```

Comment: Be awared of AWS S3 limit: 100 request/sec across all regions for upload/download both calls.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone still looking, AWS has [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#copy_to-instance_method) for this. It's actually very simple with the `aws-sdk` gem:

```
bucket = Aws::S3::Bucket.new('source-bucket')
object = bucket.object('source-key')

object.copy_to(bucket: 'target-bucket', key: 'target-key')
```

Answer (score 3):

When using the AWS SDK gem's copy_from or copy_to there are three things that aren't copied by default: ACL, storage class, or server side encryption. You need to specify them as options.

```
from_object.copy_to from_object.key, {:bucket => 'new-bucket-name', :acl => :public_read}
```

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/lib/aws/s3/s3_object.rb#L904

Comment: Are you sure this method covers the question? The author specifically asks for a copy between two buckets.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple ruby class to copy all objects from one bucket to another bucket: https://gist.github.com/edwardsharp/d501af263728eceb361ebba80d7fe324

Answer (score 2):

Multiple images could easily be copied using `aws-sdk` gem as follows:

```
require 'aws-sdk'

image_names = ['one.jpg', 'two.jpg', 'three.jpg', 'four.jpg', 'five.png', 'six.jpg']
Aws.config.update({
    region: "destination_region", 
    credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
})
image_names.each do |img|
    s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new()
    resp = s3.copy_object({
      bucket: "destinationation_bucket_name", 
      copy_source: URI.encode_www_form_component("/source_bucket_name/path/to/#{img}"), 
      key: "path/where/to/save/#{img}" 
    })      
end
```

If you have too many images, it is suggested to put the copying process in a background job.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in order to copy between buckets you must read the file's contents from the source bucket and then write it back to the destination bucket via your application's memory space. There's a snippet showing this using `aws-s3` [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4935) and another approach using `right_aws` [here](http://www.lakedenman.com/2009/10/27/copying-files-between-s3-buckets.html)

Comment: I'd like to use the snippet for aws-s3 but I'm having problems initializing the AmazoneS3Asset class. Do I simply put the snippet that defines the class in config/initializers ?

Comment: I found the answer to my comment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146946/ruby-on-rails-and-external-classes

Comment: apparently right_aws has this fucntionality, I didn't need to add the snippet. I posted more info in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

The aws-s3 gem does not have the ability to copy files in between buckets without moving files to your local machine. If that's acceptable to you, then the following will work:

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.store 'dest-key', open('http://url/to/source.file'), 'dest-bucket'
```

Comment: aws supports now this, the gem also.

Comment: Yes, this answer is now outdated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue that you had, so I cloned the source code for AWS-S3 and made a branch that has a `copy_to` method that allows for copying between buckets, which I've been bundling into my projects and using when I need that functionality.  Hopefully someone else will find this useful as well.

[View the branch on GitHub](https://github.com/fullbridge-batkins/aws-s3/tree/copy_between_buckets).