# How to use AWS Lambda to backup an S3 object to a bucket on another account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I'm attempting to use AWS Lambda to backup objects from an `assets.myapp.com` S3 bucket under `Account-A` to a `backup-assets.myapp.com` S3 bucket under `Account-B`, but I'm getting `Access Denied` no matter the `IAM` or `Bucket Policy` configuration I use.

I've got a Lambda function called `Backup-S3-Object` and it's fired by an `s3:PutObject` event trigger on the `assets.myapp.com` bucket.

The desired result is that the `Backup-S3-Object` function will the perform an `s3.copyObject` to `backup-assets.myapp.com` using the AWS-SDK for Javascript.

**The Lambda Code**

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

exports.backupObject = function(event, context, callback) {

    var data = event.Records[0];
    var sourceBucket = data.s3.bucket.name;
    var targetBucket = 'backup-' + data.s3.bucket.name;
    var key = data.s3.object.key;

    console.log('BACKUP: ' + sourceBucket + '/' + key + ' to ' + targetBucket);

    s3.copyObject({
        Bucket : targetBucket,
        CopySource : sourceBucket + '/' + key,
        Key : key,
        ACL : 'private',
        ServerSideEncryption : 'AES256'
    }, function(error, data) {

        if (error) return context.done(error);
        return context.done(null, 'Successful backup of ' + sourceBucket + '/' + key);

    });

};
```

**The Lambda Role S3 Policy**

I've got the following policy for the `Backup-S3-Lambda-Role` which is assigned to my Lambda function. This allows the Lambda function access to `List` or `Get` any object, from any bucket, under `Account-A`, which is the source account. So this policy will allow the Lambda function to get the object from `assets.myapp.com`, which is the source bucket.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**The `backup-assets.myapp.com` Bucket Policy**

And then, under `Account-B`, I've got the following bucket policy attached to the `backup-assets.myapp.com`, which is intended to allow the Lambda function, running under `Account-A`, to write to the `backup-assets.myapp.com` bucket under `Account-B`

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow PUT from Account-A Lambda function",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-A-NUMBER-HERE:role/Backup-S3-Lambda-Role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::backup-assets.myapp.com",
                "arn:aws:s3:::backup-assets.myapp.com/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**What's Happening?**

The trigger on the `assets.myapp.com` bucket fires just fine. It triggers the `Backup-S3-Object` Lambda function, and the function logic is able to determine the correct bucket names and object key to be copied, but it always fails with `Access Denied`.

I've done a test using the same setup and transferring to another bucket that's also under `Account-A` and it works just fine. So the problem is obviously with the cross-account permissions, but nothing I've tried works.

I've also attempted using the `CanonicalID` of `Account-A` as the `Principal` in the `backup-assets.myapp.com` bucket policy, but still get `Access Denied` as the resulting error.

And I've attempted using `"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-A-NUMBER-HERE:root"` as the principal, same error.

Any help?

> **A Solution:** As outlined by Matt below, the solution is that you need to include `s3:PutObject` permission *in the Lambda role policy*.
>   This is a little weird to me, but the general idea is that any
>   permissions you grant the Lambda role in the Bucket Policy of your
>   target bucket must also be replicated in the Lambda policy under your
>   source account. It seems that the Lambda role is *adopted* entirely
>   when you reference it in the Bucket Policy. To achieve this I've added
>   a second inline policy to my Lambda role that allows `s3:PutObject` to
>   the `backup-assets.myapp.com` bucket under `Account-B`. This disallows
>   the Lambda function to write to any of the source buckets, but does
>   allow it to write to the backup bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two possible problems.

1. Your IAM policy for your Lambda function is missing permissions to **write** to your backup bucket.

Try adding `s3:PutObject` into your policy like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Or, if you'd like to continue to restrict your Lambda function to **read** access only on your source bucket(s), you can add a second policy to your Lambda role allowing it to `s3:PutObject` on your backup bucket, naming your backup bucket as the resource, like so:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::backup-assets.myapp.com",
                "arn:aws:s3:::backup-assets.myapp.com/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Sometimes, using IAM roles as principals in your IAM policies is not as straight forward as you have. I'm not saying it's the problem, but let's loosen the restrictions until you get the copy working. Then you can tighten the policy.

For now, just let your target account access to the source bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Backup-Assets",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow PUT from Account-A Lambda function",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-A-NUMBER-HERE:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::backup-assets.myapp.com",
                "arn:aws:s3:::backup-assets.myapp.com/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Once copying is working, you can try adding the role back.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Matt Houser, but I think you've got the polices mixed-up. The `Backup-S3-Object` Lambda role only has `List` and `Get` permissions on the source bucket (`assets.myapp.com`) because it just needs to fetch the object from there, doesn't need to write anything to that bucket. Then I use the Bucket Policy on `backup-assets.myapp.com` to allow the Lamba role to write to the backup bucket under `Account-B`. I've tried granting `arn:aws:iam:ACCOUNT-A-NUMBER-HERE:root` already, but i'll give it another go. But I think the Lambda function doesn't fire under `root`, not sure.

Comment: Yeah, same problem using the `root` principal.

Comment: Okay, this is messed-up. When I add `s3:PutObject` to the Lambda role policy, it works. But why? That policy is supposed to dictate the permissions the Lambda function has for the source bucket, `assets.myapp.com`, which is only needs to **read** from. Why would it require `PUT` creds on the source bucket to copy an object to the `backup-assets.myapp.com` bucket?

Comment: This also works when I switch the principal back to the `Backup-S3-Object` Lambda role. But it really bugs me that I have to give `PutObject` permission to the Lambda function for my source buckets. All it needs to do is read from them, not write, so why?

Comment: Okay, did another experiment and found a config that works. I've moved the `s3:PutObject` permission into its own policy, under the Lambda role, and specified the `backup-assets.myapp.com` bucket as the resource. It works, and it removes `PUT` creds from my Lambda function on my primary buckets. Weird though. So any actions allowed by the Bucket Policy need to be replicated on the Lambda policy. Interesting.

Comment: @AJB this is because you're operating cross-account.  It's not enough for the foreign account to grant access.  You also need permission from your local account, to access the resource in the foreign account. [*"As long as the user has permission from both the resource owner and the parent account, the user will be able to access the resource."*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html) The local permission is granted by the role, in this case.  If everything is in one account, this apparent duplication isn't necessary.

Comment: Yeah, I'm grokking the concept now, and I find it very interesting. I can't really see that it adds any level of "safety", but it is an interesting way to handle permissions.

Comment: Thank you! I struggled with this for a few hours before I found this question and answer.