# How do I copy a file from one folder to another folder in same aws s3 bucket from a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I need to copy a file from one folder to another folder with new name in same aws S3 bucket. Can anyone have idea how I do it with aws-sdk gem or something else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459177/how-to-copy-file-across-buckets-using-aws-s3-gem did you checked this link?

Comment: Yes, I have already checked this actually i want to copy a file from one folder to another folder with new name in same bucket

Answer (score 1):

```
bucket = Aws::S3::Bucket.new('bucketname')

new_object = bucket.object('new_key')
aws_response = new_object.copy_from(bucket.object('source_key'))
```